# Error when opening CKSDEV project

Tags: cksdev

I just started getting this error:

> Unhandled exception occurred while calling method
>   'projectService_ProjectMenuItemsRequested' of type
>   'CKS.Dev.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Deployment.DeploymentSteps.ActivateSelectedFeaturesProjectExtension,
>   CKS.Dev, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=487fd6341a5c701f'. Exception:
>   System.NullReferenceException. Message: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

It happens when opening my project, trying to attach to IIS processes, adn trying to copy assembly to GAC. I assume it would happen on other actions as well.

I can't think of what I may have changed to cause this error. I have attempted to reinstall CKSDev, as well as rebooting my machine, and always get this problem (not intermittently).

I do not get this error when opening a smaller project, so it must be something in this project, but I have no idea.

(Cross posted here: http://cksdev.codeplex.com/discussions/391513)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I deleted my "Package" folder from the root of my project. Thankfully I had a backup.